# Can Linux report IP conflicts?

Tags: linux, redhat

If a Red Hat or other Linux host has a conflict with an IP address, is there a way to have it display a warning message on the console or in a log, like Windows and MacOS do?

i.e. my computer has an IP address configured (or received from a DHCP server) but finds another device on the network using the assigned address. Will it log the conflict?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

IP Conflict detection is standardised in [RFC 5227](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5227).  One Linux tool that implements it is [IPwatchd](http://ipwatchd.sourceforge.net/), which has a GNOME notification component (ipwatchd-gnotify).

Comment: +1 - i've never heard about that standard; thanks!

Answer (score 10):

you can use [arpwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpwatch) to find out about ip conflicts on ethernet segment you are connected to. it will alert about unseen ip-mac combinations or whenever such association change.

Comment: It also warns when it sees one box using multiple IPs.  False positives ftl :(.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `arping` command to detect conflicts over a specific IP address:

```
arping -I eth0 192.0.2.1
```

You may find multiple MAC addresses replying for that specific IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact mechanisism of how it does it, but I've seen warnings in CentOS when bringing up a network device along the lines of "Failed to bring up eth0, a device on the network already has this IP".