# Not sending an ARP request to avoid IP conflict

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, arp

I am working on Ubuntu.

I am setting a static IPv4 for my wireless interface (ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.2) and connecting to a Wireless Access point and pinging it.

I don't see in the sniffer that the machine is sending an ARP request to make sure that the static IP that it was assigned is not in use.

Why is that? rfc5227 suggests that it should.
I would expect that the machine will send an arp request to make sure that the ip it was assigned is not in use.

Answer (score 3):

The RFC itself says

> 2.1 
>   Before beginning to use an IPv4 address (whether received from manual
>      configuration, DHCP, or some other means), a host implementing this
>      specification MUST test to see if the address is already in use, by
>      broadcasting ARP Probe packets.

The `...host implementing...` suggests to me that it is not mandatory. If you search for Ubuntu and RFC 5227 you only find answers in relation to DHCP. If you move away from then the [answers to this SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/136619/can-linux-report-ip-conflicts) point to tools that implement RFC 5227 which again suggests that it is not mandatory for a host to implement it in it's network stack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. how Can i know if the kernel version i am using supports that RFC?

Comment: Implementing RFC 5227 is not mandatory. However where the RFC **is** implemented, then section 2.1 states that ARP probes before using an IP address (however this may have been configured) **are** mandatory.